# Boost::tokenizer comma separated (c++)

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

Should be an easy one for you guys.....

I'm playing around with tokenizers using Boost and I want create a token that is comma separated.   here is my code:

```
    string s = "this is, , ,  a test";
boost::char_delimiters_separator<char> sep(",");
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_delimiters_separator<char>>tok(s, sep);


for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator beg= tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end(); ++beg)
{
    cout << *beg << "\n";
}
```

The output that I want is:

```
This is


 a test
```

What I am getting is:

```
This
is
,
,
,
a
test
```

UPDATED

Comment: Similar to this question: If I have `this is,,,a test` and `cout << "<" << *beg << "> ";` modified in your code, how do I get empty strings too, as `<this is> <> <> <a string>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must give the separator to tokenizer!

```
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_delimiters_separator<char>>tok(s, sep);
```

Also, replace the deprecated char_delimiters_separator with char_separator:

```
string s = "this is, , ,  a test";
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > tok(s, sep);
for(boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> >::iterator beg = tok.begin(); beg != tok.end(); ++beg)
{
    cout << *beg << "\n";
}
```

Please note that there is also a template parameter mismatch: it's good habit to typedef such complex types: so the final version could be:

```
string s = "this is, , ,  a test";
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > t_tokenizer;
t_tokenizer tok(s, sep);
for (t_tokenizer::iterator beg = tok.begin(); beg != tok.end(); ++beg)
{
    cout << *beg << "\n";
}
```

Comment: also, Now my output separates by comma AND spaces,I want to ignore spaces and I don't want to include the comma in the output (see updated question above)...

Comment: instead of `typedef`ing things just to use iterators you can use `auto`

Comment: @Dani, actually you can't. `auto` is valid only in c++11 standard

Answer (score 0):

With modern C++, a much simpler formulation is possible than the other answer provides:

```cpp
std::string my_string = "this is, , ,  a test";

for(auto const &substring : boost::tokenizer{my_string, boost::char_separator{","}}) {
  std::cout << substring << std::endl;
}
```