# Boost::tokenizer point separated, but also keeping empty fields

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7941725/1360570) and mine is very similar to it, but it is different, so please do not mark it as duplicate.

**My question is:** How do I get the empty fields from a string?

I have a string like `std::string s = "This.is..a.test";` and I want to get the fields `<This> <is> <> <a> <test>`.

I have tried also

```
typedef boost::char_separator<char> ChSep;
typedef boost::tokenizer<ChSep> TknChSep;
ChSep sep(".", ".", boost::keep_empty_tokens);
TknChSep tok(s, sep);
for (TknChSep::iterator beg = tok.begin(); beg != tok.end(); ++beg)
{
  std::cout << "<" << *beg << "> ";
}
```

but I get `<This> <.> <is> <.> <> <.> <a> <test>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to Boost.Tokenizer's [`char_separator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm) is the `kept_delims` parameter.  It is used to specify a delimiters that will show up as tokens.  The original code is specifying that `"."` should be kept as a token.  To resolve this, change:

```
ChSep sep(".", ".", boost::keep_empty_tokens);
```

to:

```
ChSep sep(".", "", boost::keep_empty_tokens);
            // ^-- no delimiters will show up as tokens.
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "This.is..a.test";
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(
      ".", // dropped delimiters
      "",  // kept delimiters
      boost::keep_empty_tokens); // empty token policy

  BOOST_FOREACH(std::string token, tokenizer(str, sep))
  {
    std::cout << "<" << token << "> ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
<This> <is> <> <a> <test>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd skip `Boost::tokenizer`, and just use a standard regex to do the splitting:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {     
    std::string s = "This.is..a.test";

    std::regex sep{ "\\." };

    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), sep, -1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Result:

```
This
is

a
test
```