# Spliting a string with multiple delimiter and save it into a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, split, delimiter

I know there's many topics with some problems like mine but I can't find the right answer for my problem in particular.

I would like to split my string into tokens by multiples delimiter (`' '`, `'\n'`, `'('`, `')'`) and save all in my vector (Even the delimiters).

Here's the first code I made, it actually just take all lines, but now I would like to split it with the other delimiters.

```
std::vector<std::string> Lexer::getToken(std::string flow)
{
    std::string token;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::stringstream f;

    f << flow;
    while (std::getline(f, token, '\n'))
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return (tokens);
}
```

Exmaple, if I have :

`push int32(42)`

I would like to have the folowing tokens :

`push`

`int32`

`(`

`42`

`)`

Comment: but you are not saving the delimiter, it's not in the `token` you add to your container?

Comment: @Nim : Currently not, but I'd like to save them too.

Comment: There is no point in rolling your own, someone else has already done the hard work! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331648/boosttokenizer-point-seperated-but-also-keeping-empty-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using per-character logic if you think through the states involved....

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string delims = " \n()";
char c;
bool last_was_delim = true;
while (f.get(c))
    if (delims.find(c) != tokens.end())
    {
        tokens.emplace_back(1, c);
        last_was_delim = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (last_was_delim)
             tokens.emplace_back(1, c); // start new string
        else
             tokens.back() += c; // append to existing string
        last_was_delim = false;
    }
```

Obviously this considers say `"(("` or `"  "` (two spaces) to be repeated distinct delimiters, to be entered into `tokens` separately.  Tune to taste if necessary.

Equivalently, but using flow control instead of a `bool` / a different `while (f.get(c))` loop handles additional characters for an in-progress token:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string delims = " \n()";
char c;
while (f.get(c))
    if (delims.find(c) != tokens.end())
        tokens.emplace_back(1, c);
    else
    {
        tokens.emplace_back(1, c); // start new string
        while (f.get(c))
            if (delims.find(c) != tokens.end())
            {
                tokens.emplace_back(1, c);
                break;
            }
            else
                tokens.back() += c; // append to existing string
    }
```

Or, if you like `goto` statements:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string delims = " \n()";
char c;
while (f.get(c))
    if (delims.find(c) != tokens.end())
      add_token:
        tokens.emplace_back(1, c);
    else
    {
        tokens.emplace_back(1, c); // start new string
        while (f.get(c))
            if (delims.find(c) != tokens.end())
                goto add_token;
            else
                tokens.back() += c; // append to existing string
    }
```

Which is "easier" to grok is debatable....

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a regular expression for this:

```
#include <regex>

std::vector<std::string> getToken(std::string const &flow) {
  // Delimiter regex. Depending on your desired behavior, you may want to
  // remove the + from it; with the +, it will combine adjacent delimiters
  // into one. That is to say, "foo (\n) bar" will be tokenized into "foo",
  // "bar" instead of "foo", "", "", "", "", "bar".
  std::regex re("[ \n()]+");

  // range-construct result vector from regex_token_iterators
  return std::vector<std::string>(
      std::sregex_token_iterator(flow.begin(), flow.end(), re, -1),
      std::sregex_token_iterator()
    );
}
```

Comment: Could be a good idea indeed, but I'd like to avoid using Regex if possible ^^'

Comment: In a lexer? That's a bit unusual. Suit yourself, but I'm a bit surprised you're not drowning in them already.