# boost::tokenizer to consider absence of tokens between separators

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

I am using boost::tokenizer to get ';' separated fields from a `string`.
I am able to retrieve the fields as shown in the code below but i have 2 questions:

1. Is there any function which tokenizer provides to know the count of tokens in a string based on the separator provided?
2. Supposing the test string has 3 fields `a;b;c` . The following piece of code will print all of them. But i need to print empty fields too. E.g. incase of a string `a;;;b;c` the token should also contain *nothing* as 2nd and 3rd element. Or in other words the 2nd and 3rd token should be empty.

```cpp
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
namespace std;
namespace boost;
int main()
{
    string data="a;;;;b;c";
    boost::char_separator<char> obj(";");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokens(data,obj);
    cout<<endl<<tokens.countTokens();
    for(boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >::iterator it=tokens.begin();
    it!=tokens.end();
    ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331648/boosttokenizer-point-seperated-but-also-keeping-empty-fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can just count difference between end and begin.

```
const size_t count = std::distance(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
```

2) You should just construct separator right.

```
boost::char_separator<char> obj(";", "", boost::keep_empty_tokens);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5016634b6f8733a8)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just read that _space_ is considered as a separator by default. So `a;b;  c;d` would fetch only a and b because it encounters two spaces after `b;` . Is there anyway i let tokenizer stop treating spaces as token separators?

Comment: i kept the 2nd parater as " ". But it is still not working.I did it this way : `boost::char_separator<char> obj(";"," ",boost::keep_empty_tokens);
`

Comment: @anurag86 look, in my code there is no space, but just empty string.

Comment: I mean i got the answer for the 2 questions asked. I am asking now that if my string contains `;` separated fields if the fields itself contains space then the tokenizer thinks _space_ also as one of the separators. I dont want tokenizer to treat _space_ as a separator. How can i do it?

Comment: @anurag86 if you want to ignore space - just construct separator like "; " in first argument.